# Creating a self expanding stack

Tags: visual-c++, stack

```css
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Stack FillEmptyStackWithIntegersAndReturnIt();
void PopAndPrintStack(Stack Stk);
int main()
{
 {

  cout << "Creating a new Stack.\n";
  Stack IntStack = FillEmptyStackWithIntegersAndReturnIt();
  cout << "Making a copy of original stack.\n";
  Stack CopyOfIntStack;
  CopyOfIntStack = IntStack;
  cout << "Topping and Popping the original Stack:\n";
  PopAndPrintStack(IntStack);
  cout << "Topping and Popping the copy stack.\n";
  PopAndPrintStack(CopyOfIntStack);
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
void PopAndPrintStack(Stack Stk)
{
 cout << "Now printing the integers pushed on the stack.\n";
 while (!Stk.isEmpty())
 {
  cout << Stk.top().Integer << " ";
  Stk.pop();
 }
 cout << endl;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
Stack FillEmptyStackWithIntegersAndReturnIt()
{
 Stack Stk;
 cout << "We will push some integers on the stack now.\n";
 bool done = false;
 int val = int();
 while (!done)
 {
  cout << "Please enter an integer to be pushed on stack : ";
  cin >> val;
  ItemType item;
  item.Integer = val;
  Stk.push(item);
  cout << "The number of items on stack :" << Stk.getNumItems() << endl;
  cout << "The capacity of stack array is: " << Stk.getArrayCapacity() << endl;
  cout << "More data? Enter 0 to continue and 1 to exit: ";
  cin >> done;
 }
 return Stk;
}

//OUTPUT//
Creating a new Stack.
We will push some integers on the stack now.
Please enter an integer to be pushed on stack : 10
Using the existing array to push item on stack.
The number of items on stack is: 1
The number of items on stack :1
The capacity of stack array is: 1
More data? Enter 0 to continue and 1 to exit: 0
Please enter an integer to be pushed on stack : 9
Expanding the existing array to push item on stack.
Number of items in queue now: 2
The number of items on stack :2
The capacity of stack array is: 2
More data? Enter 0 to continue and 1 to exit: 0
Please enter an integer to be pushed on stack : 8
Expanding the existing array to push item on stack.
Number of items in queue now: 3
The number of items on stack :3
The capacity of stack array is: 3
More data? Enter 0 to continue and 1 to exit: 0
Please enter an integer to be pushed on stack : 7
Expanding the existing array to push item on stack.
Number of items in queue now: 4
The number of items on stack :4
The capacity of stack array is: 4
More data? Enter 0 to continue and 1 to exit: 0
Please enter an integer to be pushed on stack : 6
Expanding the existing array to push item on stack.
Number of items in queue now: 5
The number of items on stack :5
The capacity of stack array is: 5
More data? Enter 0 to continue and 1 to exit: 1
From Stack Copy Constructor.
From Stack Destructor.
Making a copy of original stack.
From Stack assignment operator.
Topping and Popping the original Stack:
From Stack Copy Constructor.
Now printing the integers pushed on the stack.
6 10 9 8 7
From Stack Destructor.
Topping and Popping the copy stack.
From Stack Copy Constructor.
Now printing the integers pushed on the stack.
6 10 9 8 7
From Stack Destructor.
From Stack Destructor.
From Stack Destructor.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have written a class for a self expanding stack using pointers and dynamic memory allocation and I can't figure out why is it that my stack is pushing it the items the way it is.

```css
#include "StackInterface.h"

class Stack :public StackInterface
{
private:
 const static int MAX = 1;
 const static int GROWBY = 1;
 int top_position;
 ItemType * items;
 size_t numItems;
 size_t arrayCapacity;
 bool isFull() const;

protected:
 void copy(const Stack& Stk);

public:
 Stack();
 void push(ItemType item);
 void pop();
 ItemType top() const;
 bool isEmpty() const;
 ~Stack();
 Stack(const Stack& st);
 const Stack& operator=(const Stack& Stk);
 size_t getArrayCapacity() const;
 size_t getNumItems() const;
};

//----------------------------------------------------

#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Stack::Stack()
{
 items = new ItemType[MAX];
 numItems = 0;
 top_position = -1;
 arrayCapacity = MAX;
}
//-------------------------------
void Stack::push(ItemType newItem)
{
 if (arrayCapacity > this->numItems)
 {
  cout << "Using the existing array to push item on stack. \n";
  top_position = (top_position + 1) % arrayCapacity;
  items[top_position] = newItem;
  numItems = numItems + 1;
  cout << "The number of items on stack is: " << numItems << endl;
 }
 else
 {
  cout << "Expanding the existing array to push item on stack. \n";
  size_t len = arrayCapacity + GROWBY;
  ItemType * Temp;

  Temp = new ItemType[len];

  for (size_t index = 0; index<this->numItems; index++)
  {
   Temp[index] = items[top_position];
   top_position = (top_position + 1) % arrayCapacity;
  }

  delete[] items;
  items = Temp;
  Temp = nullptr;
  arrayCapacity = len;
  top_position = numItems -1;
  top_position = (top_position + 1) % arrayCapacity;
  items[top_position] = newItem;
  this->numItems = this->numItems + 1;
  cout << "Number of items in queue now: " << numItems << endl;
 }
}
```

When I run and enter the following in order 10 9 8 7 6
I get the following output: 6 10 9 8 7
When its supposed to top like this: 6 7 8 9 10

If any more of the code is needed I can provide.

Comment: I'd prefer using a linked list structure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: If you want an answer involving a linked list, let me know!

Comment: Why don't you post a minimum working example? what is the value of MAX?

Comment: I've updated the post so that there is a working example

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've solved my problem, I just had to edit

```css
for (size_t index = 0; index<this->numItems; index++)
  {
   Temp[index] = items[(top_position + 1) % arrayCapacity];
   top_position = (top_position + 1) % arrayCapacity;
   
  }
```